# How to bring back mysteriously missing contract in Kerbal?

Tags: kerbal-space-program, cheats

For reasons unknown contract "Explore Mun" disappeared for me. I can't see it in accepted, can't see it in finished, nowhere. Not even in Alt+F12 debug console. I got the contract to explore Minmus all right. So what can I do do get this contract back?

I guess it might be because I crashed my game soon after I accepted this contract, if that's of any relevance.

Sad fact is - I was sure I have this contract accepted, so I proceeded with setting unmanned ScanSat probe in Mun orbit. The fact this didn't trigger contract stage made me look again. If the craft in orbit hides contract from me, is there a way to remove it, and all traces of it, from the game persistence file? Because that would answer my main question in this situation.

Comment: Have you been to the mun without the contract or even to a further away world? The general achievement contracts only appear when it's something you haven't already done yet.

Comment: @Philipp seems so. See my updated answer. Is there a way around that now?

Answer (score 3):

OK. It's not satisfying but here is what I did:

1. Opened Alt+F12 console
2. Added new "explore body" contract - it added second Minmus contract
3. Accepted it
4. Closed KSP
5. In persistence file, changed body of contract and it's parameters from 3 (Minmus) to 2 (Mun).
6. I should have change rewards, too, but i don't know what they should be
7. Turn on KSP
8. Load game
9. Profit