# What is the list of career mode general achievement contracts?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

As @Philipp points out in a comment to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232034/how-to-bring-back-mysteriously-missing-contract-in-kerbal) question:

> The general achievement contracts only appear when it's something you haven't already done yet.

To maximize my career performance I'd like not to go exploring before the corresponding achievement contract is available.

Some of this list, that I've already encountered in-game (as of 1.0.4) are:

- Orbit Kerbin
- Explore Mun
- Explore Duna

Is there a comprehensive list, so I could *catch-em-all*?

Answer (score -1):

The full list is presented [here](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/List_of_story_line_contracts) but I'm not sure if it's up to date or not.

The general gist of that link is correct though. After you're done on Kerbin, the basic flow is: Flyby, Orbit, Return from Orbit, Land, Return from Landing, Retrieve science data from, EVA, rendevous, dock, create orbital station.

A good rule to follow is to simply NEVER exceed the parameters of a given contract.  If it says 'flyby' then don't enter orbit, and don't perform any contract that requires you to do something the World Firsts Society hasn't already had you do.

Comment: Also, after you enter orbit, don't de-orbit right away; go and accept the World Firsts contract for returning from orbit, and _then_ return.